# Restarts boots into BIOS. Turn off/on boots into Linux

Tags: linux, bios, uefi

On a [fitlet-H](https://www.fit-pc.com/web/products/fitlet/fitlet-h-the-hardened-version-of-fitlet/) PC I have installed a brand new SSD SAMSUNG 870 EVO 1 TB. I have tried installing both Linux Mint and Ubuntu MATE and I have the same boot issue.

1. If I turn off the PC and then turns it on it boots fine into Linux OS.
2. If I restarts the OS, the PC boots into the BIOS. Using "Save & Exit" boots into the BIOS again. I have to turn off the PC to boot into OS.

I have tried all kind of "Boot Orders" in the BIOS, but the problem continues (picture is the current)

I have tried resetting BIOS to defaults

I have upgraded the BIOS firmware to newest version.

[image]
[image]

After turn off/on and pressing DEL to enter BIOS Ubuntu is listed as below. This disappears again after next restart.

[image]

Comment: HOW do you "restart the OS"?

Comment: Using a mouse and pressing the restart from a menu (UI)

Comment: After you install the OS (or after you manually reinstall the bootloader using `grub-install`), does a dedicated entry for Ubuntu/Mint appear among "Boot Options"?

Comment: @user1686 it might have been there. It is there if I turn off/on and presses DEL to enter BIOS. After "Save & Exit" it is gone again. See new screenshot

Comment: There might be a problem with your new disk.

Comment: May not help, but the BIOS is 2017... is there any more recent version of it?

Comment: @harrymc how do i check this?

Comment: @Sylvain this is the newest firmware

Comment: @Stig I'm not sure it's a disk problem, but there are various warnings/issues about 870 EVO (but I have a couple and no problem). On reddit and such [place](https://www.techpowerup.com/forums/threads/samsung-870-evo-beware-certain-batches-prone-to-failure.291504/). I don't know about Linux but you should find a tool to check for SMART infos. Or the Samsung Magician app if avail for linux. Just FYI.

Comment: Hello. What is under the "UEFI Hard Disk Drive BBS Priorities" option at the bottom of the last picture? Usually you set the priority of devices (HDD, USB stick, etc), then the individual priorities within a device (HDD) below there. That usually holds the answer, and "grub" or "distro"  or whatever should figure there.

Comment: You may check the SMART attributes of the disk. If you need advice, paste them into your post.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's a bug in the BIOS/UEFI firmware and you can do nothing. But you can optimize the settings and give it a try:

- disable PXE boot
- disable CSM support
- move the HDD boot option to the very top

You can also check your Samsung SSD for [firmware](https://semiconductor.samsung.com/consumer-storage/support/tools/) updates.

Also when you restarted the PC and it boots into BIOS you can analyse the problem a little more. Insert an Ubuntu USB boot stick and run `lsblk` to see if the SSD is there. Run `dd` to see if it's readable (replace `sda` with your disk):

```
sudo dd if=/dev/sda of=/dev/null count=1024 status=progress
```

You could also give it a try and roll back to an older BIOS version. But that may be blocked.

Also you could install the OSes in BIOS mode instead of UEFI but that isn't really satisfying either.